# Using cast() inside a select in spark.sql

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to do a simple thing: an inner join between two tables, but one of them have a column that was renamed and the data_type is wrong. So I want to use cast() and change the name of the column.
I did this:

```
spark.sql(f'''SELECT nr_cpf_base_srf as nr_cpf,
                 cd_fon_ren,
                 dt_ref_ren,
                 vl_ren,
                 dt_incl_ren_avld,
                 dt_bxa_ren,
                 cd_usu_rsp_atl,
          cast(nr_cpf AS decimal (14,0))
          FROM DB2DFE.REN_AVLD_PF as A
          INNER JOIN sbx_d4n0cbf.pss_cpf_cli_msl as B
          ON a.nr_cpf = b.NR_CPF
       ''').createOrReplaceTempView('temp_x')
```

The table `DB2DFE.REN_AVLD_PF` have a column `nr_cpf_base_srf` which I want to change to `nr_cpf` so I can build the inner join with `sbx_d4n0cbf.pss_cpf_cli_msl`. But the data type of `nr_cpf_base_srf` is nit right: it should be decimal(14,0), thus I used `cast()`. It raises the error:

```
SparkStatementException: "cannot resolve '`a.nr_cpf`' given input columns: [B.dt_mvtc, A.dt_bxa_ren, B.NR_CPF,
B.cd_cli, A.dt_incl_ren_avld, A.cd_fon_ren, A.vl_ren, A.cd_usu_rsp_atl, A.dt_ref_ren, A.nr_cpf_base_srf];
line 11 pos 17;
```

It must be a really simple thing, but I do not know how to do it and could not find any answer. So: what is wrong? please.

Comment: You say the column is `nr_cpf_base_srf`, but your SQL uses `nr_cpf` - those are different names.

Comment: yes, but I selected ´nr_cpf_base_srf´ as ´nr_cpf´. Wasn't it right? The first line, I think, do this, no?

Comment: You cannot reference other columns in the same `SELECT` projection clause. Only MySQL lets you do that, but it's a violation of ISO SQL. Apache Spark doesn't allow it.

Comment: and then I cast it with the new type I want. But I am not sure how to ´SELECT `nr_cpf_base_srf` as nr_cpf

Comment: Ok, I see. Thus I need to change the column name before the select, on another clause? I mean, I call a select to change the name, and then a new select to do the query I want?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISO SQL (which Apache Spark implements, *mostly*) does not let you reference other columns or expressions from the same `SELECT` projection clause.

So you cannot do this:

```
SELECT
    ( a + 123 ) AS b,
    ( b + 456 ) AS c
FROM
    someTable
```

(Arguably, ISO SQL *should* allow this, as otherwise you need a CTE or outer-query and that will balloon the textual size of your query: the ISO SQL design committee needs to start considering their own ergonomics).

Anyway, change your query to *not* reference column expressions:

```
SELECT
    nr_cpf_base_srf AS nr_cpf,
    cd_fon_ren,
    dt_ref_ren,
    vl_ren,
    dt_incl_ren_avld,
    dt_bxa_ren,
    cd_usu_rsp_atl,
    CAST( nr_cpf_base_srf AS decimal (14,0) )
FROM
    DB2DFE.REN_AVLD_PF AS a
    INNER JOIN sbx_d4n0cbf.pss_cpf_cli_msl AS b ON a.nr_cpf = b.NR_CPF
```

---

If you really do want to alias the column *before* you `CAST` it then you'll need an outer-query:

```
SELECT
    t.*,
    CAST( t.nr_cpf AS decimal (14,0) )
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            nr_cpf_base_srf AS nr_cpf,
            cd_fon_ren,
            dt_ref_ren,
            vl_ren,
            dt_incl_ren_avld,
            dt_bxa_ren,
            cd_usu_rsp_atl
        FROM
            DB2DFE.REN_AVLD_PF as A
            INNER JOIN sbx_d4n0cbf.pss_cpf_cli_msl AS B ON a.nr_cpf_base_srf = b.NR_CPF
    ) AS t
```

Or a CTE:

```
WITH t AS (

    SELECT
        nr_cpf_base_srf AS nr_cpf,
        cd_fon_ren,
        dt_ref_ren,
        vl_ren,
        dt_incl_ren_avld,
        dt_bxa_ren,
        cd_usu_rsp_atl
    FROM
        DB2DFE.REN_AVLD_PF as A
        INNER JOIN sbx_d4n0cbf.pss_cpf_cli_msl AS B ON a.nr_cpf_base_srf = b.NR_CPF
)
SELECT
    t.*,
    CAST( t.nr_cpf AS decimal (14,0) )
FROM
    t
```

Comment: it is not working. The exception raised gives reference to some columns of `sbx_d4n0cbf.pss_cpf_cli_msl` that I do not want in the end. Maybe my problem is bigger than what I was expecting.

Comment: @Dimitri I can't help you further unless you post the full details of that new exception

Comment: it is the same as before, actually: `SparkStatementException: "cannot resolve '`a.nr_cpf`' given input columns: [a.dt_incl_ren_avld, a.cd_fon_ren, b.cd_cli, a.vl_ren, b.NR_CPF, a.dt_ref_ren, a.cd_usu_rsp_atl, a.dt_bxa_ren, a.nr_cpf_base_srf, b.dt_mvtc]; line 12 pos 63;`

Comment: it gives reference to `b.dt_mvtc` which is a column from the second table

Comment: @Dimitri Ah, I missed that. I've updated my answer to use `nr_cpf_base_srf` in the `JOIN` condition as ISO SQL does not allow queries to reference column expressions in `JOIN` conditions either.

Comment: perfect! It worked. I need to study more about sql hehe thanks for your time, it really helped!!!